# Configuring CORS with express and making requests on the front end with axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, cors, axios

I'm trying to get a JSON object from one of my sever routes using axios in a react component.

Here's the relevant server code

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.use(require('morgan')('combined'))
app.use(require('cookie-parser')())
app.use(require('body-parser').urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(require('express-session')({ secret: 'keyboard cat', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }))

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept')

  next()
})

app.get('/',
  function (req, res, next) {
    res.send(req.user)
  }
)
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080)
```

And here is the relevant axios function request in my component

```
 getUser () {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/', {mode: 'cors', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'})
      .then(res =>
        res.data
      )
      .then(user =>
        this.setState({
          user: user
        })
      )
      .catch(console.error())
  }
```

This code works if I disable Cross-Origin Restrictions in browser development settings (I receive the correct JSON object), but it doesn't work by default as it should. I've tried using [this CORS express middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/cors), manually setting the header mode to "cors" instead of "no-cors", setHeader instead of header in the res.header section, adding 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' and related headers to my axios request and more. I'm unsure how to fix this issue.

When I don't disable Cross-Origin-Restriction in browser I only ever receive an empty string response, no headers set except sometimes 'content-type' and I receive no error message telling me anything. It goes through with the exact same status code as if it were responding correctly.

Comment: Install CORS middle ware it should work `npm install cors`

Answer (score 5):

Install the cors [middleware at npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

This code then will enable all CORS requests.

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

app.use(cors());
```

Comment: Ok so I've tried this again and after refreshing the page over and over I realized it does work. However now I have a race condition or something else that's causing the json object to not be received 100% of the time. Do you know what could be causing this? Do I have to configure the cors middleware to behave asynchronously?

Comment: No I don't think that is your problem, you can however set the cros middleware. Here is the Docs for that. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors